# A single quote in a column breaks the dynamic string

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Please help me with a simple formatting of a dynamic string that I'm building so I can run multiple statements at once.

Here is the exact code I have which is breaking when the column value has a single quote and I'm unable to wrap the column text with the proper quotation. I tried using double quotes and `quotename` function but none worked.

```
declare @str varchar(max)
set @str = ''

declare @addgo varchar(20)
set @addgo = 'GO'

declare @newline varchar(50)
set @newline = char(13)+char(10)

select @str = coalesce(@str, '') + 'sp_addmessage @msgnum =  ' + convert(varchar(50), error) + ' , @severity = 16' + ', @msgtext = N''' + "description" + '''' 
              + @newline + @addgo + @newline from [msdb].dbo.sysmessages 
              where error = '777970005'
print @str
```

Result:

```
sp_addmessage @msgnum =  777970005 ,@severity = 16,@msgtext = N'Management group with id '%s' is not a member of this Data Warehouse or you do not have permissions to perform actions for that management group'
GO
```

Comment: You could use double quotes for your dynamic statement or replace quotes by doubling them where you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Like @KamilG said, use the `replace` function:

```
select @str= coalesce(@str,'')+'sp_addmessage @msgnum =  '+convert(varchar(50),error)+' ,@severity = 16'+',@msgtext = N'''+replace(description,'''','''''')+''''
+ @newline+@addgo+@newline from [msdb].dbo.sysmessages
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil & Sam for your suggestions. it worked like a charm :)